# Determine time slices in the dataset

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a large dataset, with multiple columns, one of them being a timestamp. The data was gathered for a few weeks, so the timestamps start let's say on the `18th Jan 2017` and end up on the `05 Feb 2017`. I'm running a `python3` simulator which is using this data. For querying the dataset I use `sqlite3`. I would like to instead of reading in the whole dataset at once, read it as time slices (a slice might be of size 1 hour, 1 day or 1 week). is there any efficient way to do that?

For example, imagine my dataset is as follows:

```
A | ... | 18:01:2017 13:59:01
B | ... | 18:01:2017 14:09:15
C | ... | 18:01:2017 14:36:45
D | ... | 18:01:2017 14:37:01
E | ... | 18:01:2017 19:31:13
...
X | ... | 19:01:2017 09:56:59
Y | ... | 19:01:2017 09:58:05
Z | ... | 19:01:2017 10:23:15
```

So what I want to have as an output of time slices is the following (assume time slice is 1 hour):

```
output: [A, B, C, D], [E, ...], ...., [X, Y, Z]
```

Since SQL outputs the result in the form of a table I would like maybe something like that (even though any other way of grouping records into time slices will work), when I add additional column, which defines to which time slice the record belongs

```
1| A | ... | 18:01:2017 13:59:01
1| B | ... | 18:01:2017 14:09:15
1| C | ... | 18:01:2017 14:36:45
1| D | ... | 18:01:2017 14:37:01
2| E | ... | 18:01:2017 19:31:13
...
n| X | ... | 19:01:2017 09:56:59
n| Y | ... | 19:01:2017 09:58:05
n| Z | ... | 19:01:2017 10:23:15
```

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more detail of what you want. It sounds like you want (example) all the rows for 20th Jan 2017. What's in the other columns and how do you want that to appear in the output? Are the rows being aggregated in some way (avg, sum, max, etc.)?

Comment: @mypetlion I added a little example, hope this showes what I want

Comment: A SELECT query outputs rows and columns, in the form of a table. Show what you want the output to be.

Comment: @CL. I added a suggestion, but i don't have any strong requirements of how the output should look like. What I just want is to make the records grouped into time slices

Comment: Why are A and B in the same slice? Are you required to use this date format?